# Assignability of function parameters in golang

Tags: go

[Runnable on playground](http://play.golang.org/p/GWLstSp7cg)

```
type Boolean bool

func takes_bool(b bool) {
    fmt.Printf("%t\n", b)
}

func takes_boolean(b Boolean) {
    fmt.Printf("%t\n", b)
}
```

When I invoke the following:

```
takes_bool(Boolean(false))
takes_bool(Boolean(true))
```

I get:

```
cannot use Boolean(false) (type Boolean) as type bool in function argument
cannot use Boolean(true) (type Boolean) as type bool in function argument
```

The rules on assignability seems to *NOT* disallow it i.e. at least one is not a named type & both have the same underlying type:

```
type Boolean bool

vs

bool
```

Answer (score 2):

On a careful reading of http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types it seems `bool` is considered a named type (as are `int` and `float` and friends). The phrase "unnamed types" only refer to type literals like `interface{}` and `struct{}`.

Comment: function `takes_boolean` can accept both bare `true` and `false`. So now you have 2 named types.

Comment: `bool` and `Boolean` are both named types. However, bareword `true` and `false` are untyped constant literals, falling under the last bullet point in http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability See also http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants