# Assigning slices of equivalent types doesn't work

Tags: go

Why doesn't this work?

```
package main

type Word uint8
type Memory []Word

func main() {
    bytes := []uint8{}
    memory := Memory{}
    bytes = memory
}
```

The compiler generates this error:

```
9:9: cannot use memory (type Memory) as type []byte in assignment
```

As I understand it, `[]uint8` and `Memory` should be mutually assignable.

Comment: Took a second look after your comment to zerkms a few minutes ago. There is more going on here than what it seems. For some reason, even a `uint8` is not assignable to a `Word` (and vice versa). https://play.golang.org/p/BrU8mz4ZdUh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assignability of function parameters in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948349/assignability-of-function-parameters-in-golang)

Comment: Discovered the subtlety :)

Comment: This seems to go into quite a bit of detail. https://go101.org/article/value-conversions-assignments-and-comparisons.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [assignability rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)

In this particular case none of those is held, so the types are not assignable.

Given you mentioned this answer is not detailed enough - let's run through every assignability rule: (for ease let's use `A` as a substitute for `[]uint8` and `B` as a substitute for `[]Word`)

- x's type is identical to T. --- Nope, `A` is not identical to `B`
- x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type. --- Nope, both are defined types
- T is an interface type and x implements T. --- None of them is an interface
- x is a bidirectional channel value, T is a channel type, x's type V and T have identical element types, and at least one of V or T is not a defined type. --- None of them is a channel
- x is the predeclared identifier nil and T is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type. --- None of them holds `nil` value
- x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T. --- Nope, no constants involved

So, as you can see - there is no way `A` is assignable to `B`.

If you declare Memory as `type Memory []uint8` it would work (as [@RayfenWindspear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276480/rayfenwindspear) mentioned in the comments), I'm sure though the question roots is more "why" not "how to fix".

Comment: Explained in the spec, but it's useful to note for this specific instance, cutting out `Word` and just using `[]uint8` makes them assignable.

Comment: My comment (which could have been better) was to illustrate that this is a case of `a = b` and `b = c` but with Go assignability of types, that doesn't mean `a = c`.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear it's probably even a bit more complicated because of covariance (lack of it)

Comment: I read the assignability rules before posting, but I can't figure out why in that specific case ```[]uint8``` is not equal to ```[]Word```. Plus, I specifically asked "Why", not "how to fix". Thus, your answer isn't enought.

Comment: @MartínStraus I've run through the assignability rules for better clarity